# cloudera manager cluster configuration getting overriden

Tags: hive, cloudera

I have cluster with cloudera installed on it with all services running. I have to make one configuration change for hive(used in hive-site.xml). I have changed into machine where hive is installed.
/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml

I did changes in machine where hive is installed and changes gets reflected and gettign desired results.But after restarting cluster changes are getting overridden.

Please let me know what should i do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not hand edit the client `hive-site.xml` if your cluster is being managed by Cloudera Manager. Instead, there is a configuration you can make in Cloudera Manager that will handle the edits for you.

1. In Cloudera Manager go to `Hive` > `Configuration` > `Service-Wide` > `Advanced`.
2. Add or overrride configurations in `Hive Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hive-site.xml` (your name may be different depending on your CM version).
3. Click `Save Changes` button.
4. Click `Actions` button and click `Deploy Client Configuration`. This will update `hive-site.xml` across all of your cluster hosts.

Comment: Hi, I am using cloudera manager Cloudera Express 5.2.1 version. I am not able to find Hive Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hive-site.xml. I clicked hive service and configuration. made the changes. and when trying to deploy it is failed.